# "@php_bin@" is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file

Tags: selenium, yii, phpunit

I using PHPUnit and Selenium Server to testing Yii Application, 
i m using xp operating system. and i install PHPUnit_Selenium (1.0.1) and other software.actually i follow this bellow instruction to install http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php?/topic/14995-wamp-netbeans-phpunit-selenium-yii/

and i also download the selenium-server-standalone-2.20.0.jar file and through command prompted i started server using java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.0b3.jar command..

and after that i opened new command prompt and i tried to test my simple hello world yii application. and i invoked this command phpunit functional/SiteTest.php  and ya i also set the Test_Base_URL in webtestcase ..

but after invoking above command for test.. some process going on and 2 or 3 times firefox opened and closed automatically and at the end i got this error
"@php_bin@" is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file

even i attached screen shots of both cmd prompt ... 
http://s14.postimage.org/o057x7wox/1cmd.jpg

Answer (score 4):

You should replace @php_bin@ by the path to the php binary. I guess PEAR or PHPUnit installer was supposed to do that.